# Menu is not displaying in Magento Admin

Tags: magento, menu, admin

I want to add a section in magento dashboard for a particular user type with user add/edit/delete facility, so I have created a module for magento Admin but it not diplay in Admin menu.
I want to display association menu in magento admin.

Although it is displaying in system -> config ->advance to give enable/disable facility. 
The config xml is.
        
      
        
            
                0.1.0

```
    <global>
        <models>
            <association>
                <class>yanga_association_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>association_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </association>
            <association_mysql4>
                <class>yanga_association_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <association>
                        <table>association</table>
                    </association>
                </entities>
            </association_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <association_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>yanga_association</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </association_setup>
            <association_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </association_write>
            <association_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </association_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <association>
                <class>yanga_association_Block</class>
            </association>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <association>
                <class>yanga_association_Helper</class>
            </association>
        </helpers>
    </global>
     <admin>
        <routers>
            <association>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Yanga_Association</module>
                    <frontName>association</frontName>
                </args>
            </association>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <association module="association">
            <title>Association</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>              
            <children>
                <items module="association">
                    <title>Manage Association</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                       <action>association/adminhtml_association</action>
                </items>

            </children>
        </association>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <Association>
                                        <title>Association Module</title>
                                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    </Association>
                                </children>
                             </config>
                         </children>
                    </system>
                    <Yanga_Association>
                        <title>System Configuration Tab</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </yanga_Association>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <association>
                <file>association.xml</file>
            </association>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Kindly provide us the solution if have.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access sytem settings  than you have to code like

```
<config translate="title">
                        <title>Configuration</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/association</action>
                    </config>
```

Instead of .Replace this code with  and check it.Hops it works

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your menu's permission in your acl declaration, your ACL should look like this -:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <Association>
                                    <title>Association Module</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </Association>
                            </children>
                         </config>
                     </children>
                </system>
                <association>
                   <title>Association</title>
                   <children>
                          <items translate="title" module="association">
                              <title>Manage Association</title>
                          </items>
                   </children>
                </association>
                <Yanga_Association>
                    <title>System Configuration Tab</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </yanga_Association>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>`
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers
S